# filter data that i loaded with core data with NSSearchField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nssearchfield

How can i use `NSSearchField` for filter data that i load into program with core data ?

i want to do that from code not in interface with binding

(please give me tutorial about it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably not a more authoritative expert (outside of Apple) on Core Data than the folks at cimgf.com.  Here's a tutorial that should help you accomplish exactly what you need.

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/11/25/adding-itunes-style-search-to-your-core-data-application/

EDIT:
You can further filter the data without going back to disk by using another NSPredicate on the array.  If you have a `NSFetchedResultsController` called `myFetchController` and a `NSPredicate` named `myPredicate` you can do the following.

```
NSArray * results = [myFecthController fetchedObjects];
NSArray * filteredResults = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
```

Comment: thank you.in this example each time that we want to filter data we set predicate to array controller,does array controller reload data from persistence store?

Comment: It is possible to filter what is already in the fetchedResults array.  However, if you change the NSPredicate and perform the fetch again, the results will be loaded again from the persistent store.

Comment: in this example how can i do it that the result doesn't reload from persistent store (because of time for accessing disk)

Comment: You can also speed things up dramatically by indexing the attribute on which you're filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is information on using a predicate with an NSFetchRequest.

See [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1) on predicate programming.

No? Well have you been to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SearchFields/Articles/AddingSearchField.html) on search fields?

Comment: no,i want to do that with nssearchfield, i load all of data from persistent store to program and hold them in nsmutablearray,now i want to filter them with search field

Comment: Oh, so core data was just a red herring.  Added another link to the answer.